# SIMPER test: average vs cumsum?

Tags: r, vegan

I am running a simper test and I do not understand the output of the columns 'average' and 'cumsum'. I don't really understand the difference between the 2.

From ?simper the manual says average is 'Species contribution to average between-group dissimilarity.' so I understand this as the average contribution to the dissimilarity. cumsum is 'Ordered cumulative contribution. These are based on item average, but they sum up to total 1.' but I do not understand what does means?

If I am interested in what species are contributing the most to the dissimilarity, should I only look at the 'average' column?

Thank you

Comment: Average is in the same units (and scale) of the original data. Cumulative sum here appears to be the cumulative proportion of data at or below each value; I'm not a user of the `vegan` package, but I'll interpret that to be a cumulative distribution function, where the area under the curve is by definition always "1", and its utility is to know how much of the data is at/below (or at/above) a specific value. It is unitless.

Comment: hi @r2evans can you explain what you mean by 'appears to be the cumulative proportion of data at or below each value'? so if I am looking at contribution by specific species, the cumsum is not relevant? only the average value?

Comment: it sounds like you're asking more about the theory behind that method of analysis than about the programming itself; I think this question would do better at [stats.se] where the theory behind it is better covered